# Loading OpenCV Image To Scikit Learn

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn

I'm programming a machine learning script to take pictures and label it. I have my dataset in a folder and I add them into array and create another array for labels. when i try to use svm.fit it gives the error :

```
File "scikit.py", line 43, in <module>
    clf.fit(arrayimg, arraylabel)
  File "/home/mkmeral/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 151, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')
  File "/home/mkmeral/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 521, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "/home/mkmeral/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 405, in check_array
    % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

And here is the script I wrote:

```
import cv2
import numpy as py
from sklearn import svm

camera_port = 0
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
ramp_frames = 5

def getImage():
    retval, im = camera.read()
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return gray_image

def insertToArray(arrayone, arraytwo, no, true):
    if (true==1):
        directory = "/home/mkmeral/Desktop/opencv/strue/"
        arraytwo.append(1)
    else:
        directory = "/home/mkmeral/Desktop/opencv/sfalse/"
        arraytwo.append(0)

    im = cv2.imread(directory + str(no) + ".png")
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    arrayone.append(gray_image)

arrayimg = []
arraylabel = []
count = 1
while (count<43):
    insertToArray(arrayimg, arraylabel, count, 1)
    print("True = " , count)
    count = count + 1

count = 0
while (count<43):
    insertToArray(arrayimg, arraylabel, count, 0)
    print("False = ", count)
    count = count + 1

print("Done adding to arrays")
clf = svm.SVC()
print("Done adding to arrayssss")
clf.fit(arrayimg, arraylabel)

print("Done fitting")
for i in xrange(ramp_frames):
    temp = getImage()

testimage = getImage()

clf.predict(testimage)
```

How can I fit those images to Scikit learn and would it make a problem to predict the image taken from webcam?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on the image processing side but I'm guessing that your `getImage` function is returning a 2d array for each image. Where as `sckit-learn` will be expecting a 1d array for each training instance. Assuming that all of your images are of the same size then the following should work

```
def getImage():
    retval, im = camera.read()
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return gray_image.flatten()
```

This will convert each of your images into a 1d array. If your images are not all the same size then you will need to do some image processing steps, such as resizing or down sampling.